# Error Cannot find module paths json npm

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3, npm

I'm trying to install google Transport Tracker from thin like
https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/transport-tracker/start

I did all the steps from cmd win 10 but I stuck in step `npm install`, and seems wind issue.

I am trying now google cloud shell and also stuck in `npm` run main step and got this error:

```js
ghzoan@jernas-193723:~/backend$ npm run main

> transport-tracker-server@1.0.0 main /home/ghzoan/backend
> node main.js

module.js:529
    throw err;

Error: Cannot find module './paths.json'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ghzoan/backend/main.js:53:26)
at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:201:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:626:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! transport-tracker-server@1.0.0 main: `node main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the transport-tracker-server@1.0.0 main script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in
```

I got same the error with backend and map folders.

You can see how the site look till now [gps.jernascenter.com](https://gps.jernascenter.com/).

It's been more than a week which I'm trying to install this script.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you are getting this error is because node cannot find your .json file.

Be absolutely certain that you are telling node *exactly* where paths.json is located in your require statement.

This isn’t necessarily easy, but using a good editor or IDE works for me. It gives me

1. A good visual overview of my project directory and subdirectories
2. Alerts me when the file path argument to a require statement cannot be resolved (before running the code)
3. Generates the relative file path for me and places it in the clipboard so I can just paste into the require statement